# Why this C++ program can't get the output in the text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream> 
#include<iomanip> 
#include<string>

using namespace std;

char calculate_grade(double avg);

char calculate_grade(double avg) {
    if (avg >= 75) { return 'A'; }
    else if (avg >= 65) { return 'B'; }
    else if (avg >= 55) { return 'C'; }
    else if (avg >= 40) { return 'D'; }
    else { return 'E'; }
}

int main() {
    ifstream infile("Data.txt");
    ofstream outfile("ResultData.out");

    string name;
    double score;

    outfile << left << setw(10) << "Name"
        <<right << setw(10) << "score1"
        <<right << setw(10) << "score2"
        <<right << setw(10) << "score3"
        <<right << setw(10) << "avg"
        <<right << setw(10) << "grade" << endl;

    while (infile >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> name) {
        double avg = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0;

        char grade = calculate_grade(avg);

        outfile << setw(10) << name << " "
            << setw(10) << score1 << " "
            << setw(10) << score2 << " "
            << setw(10) << score3 << " "
            << setw(10) << avg << " "
            << setw(10) << grade << " " << endl;

    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the content of a text file to let C++ help me calculate the average score and grade of the students and then output it in the text file, but I can't get it. i don't how to do it or anywhere is wrong

I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm sorry if it does have a simple answer. But anyway, I've been debugging this for few hour and I looked online for few time also

Comment: Do proper debugging step by step to find when it fails. It is the only way to learn. How do you even know it located the file? You don’t qualify the path to it.

Comment: Please use some kind of standard indentation. Your editor most likely can indent code for you.

Comment: Please show a few lines from StudentData.txt, a few lines from ResultData.out if it is created, and any and all error messages you get. Also describe how you've been debugging this.

Comment: As already requested, please ***post*** the contents of your text files, ***Data.txt*** and ***ResultData.out***, plus any ***errors*** you're getting, and how you're ***debugging*** this. All of these are ***necessary*** for ***you*** to get ***help***. Good luck!

Comment: Try using the absolute path for ***Data.txt***, it might not exist in the same folder as your project.

Answer (score 0):

Content of file matters. And you didn't even check if file is opened. There will be no errors unless you write code to process them.

Also there is a problem with input. name is a string. `infile >> name` would eat away whole record.